# EC2 - ROOT & SUDO not working

Tags: ssh, root, amazon-web-services

I've setup an EC2 instance(PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin).

Last night I accidentally execute some command that messed up the permissions.

I was able to login as `root` before (to ssh using puTTy) but now when I try to login using `root` I get error which says login as `ec2-user` instead of `root`.

Now, If I log in using `ec2-user` and do `sudo`. I get error `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`.
When I try to login using `su` or `su root`. I get `Password:` and I didn't set any password and default `NO PASSWORD` is not working, too.

Now, I can't give permissions to `sudo` for `root` because `sudo` is broken and I can't login as `root` to change permissions because it's asking for password.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem.

Comment: I just used the long/only-possible-way, create another instance.Attach faulty volume to the new one and then fix permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the command that was run was a chmod or chown command that modified the OS files ("sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?").  This was probably a recursive (-R) change or a * change.

Therefore fixing everything that was broken is often not worth the effort.

I would:

1. Take snapshot of each volume associated with your instance.
2. Create a Volume from each snapshot.
3. Attach those volumes to a new instance.
4. Mount them.
5. Review root's history from the broken server to see what happened.
6. Backup all your data (web directories, database files, etc.)
7. Create a new instance to take over for the old broken instance.
8. Restore to the new instance.
9. Delete the old instance.
10. Shutdown the instance that was for mounting the volumes created from the snap shots.
11. Wait a few days to make sure everything is working.
12. CAREFULLY, delete volumes and snapshots and instances that are no longer in use.

Also look into Elastic IPs, Chef, SaltStack, and periodic automatic snapshots (careful, this can get expensive if done wrong.)